# Load a PNG image file for display on a Vaadin Flow layout as a Image object

Tags: image, resources, png, vaadin, vaadin-flow

Vaadin Flow offers an [`Image`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/11.0.1/com/vaadin/flow/component/html/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) class, representing an HTML `img` tag.

If I have a file named `logo.png` stored in the `resources` folder of my Vaadin 12 app, how do I load that file for display as an `Image` on a layout?

The example for [`Image` in the Vaadin 8 Sampler](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-presentation/image) shows code no longer relevant as I cannot find a `ClassResource` class in Flow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can put that logo under what your build tool/setup considers a root for web resources under the directory `frontend/...` and then reference that resource like so:

```
new Image("frontend/images/logo.png", "Acme Inc. Logo")
```

Answer (score 4):

If your resource is not located inside the root for web resources, [this doc page](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/advanced/tutorial-dynamic-content) gives a hint on using a `com.vaadin.flow.server.StreamResource` to provide the data by an `java.io.InputStream`:

```java
StreamResource res = new StreamResource("logo-image.png", () -> {
    // eg. load image data from classpath (src/main/resources/images/image.png)
    return MainView.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("images/image.png");
});
Image imageFromStream = new Image( res,"Alternativ text description for logo image");
add(imageFromStream);
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was in the location of the file:
If you use: `new Image("img/logo.png", "Logo")` then the file location should be `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/img/logo.png` in Spring Boot project